# Get user access token with permission via php with FB sdk 3.2

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I'm admin of a page and I have my app with ID and Secret.
When I go to [Graph api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) I can easily take my User Access Token with permission "*manage-pages*".
I need to take the same via php, using the **FB sdk 3.2**. 
I managed to run only this:

```
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => 'My app ID',
        'secret' => 'My app secret',
    ));

    //This token is: "My app ID|My app secret"
    print_r($facebook->getAccessToken());
```

How Can I get the user access token with permission via php with fb sdk 3.2?

Can somebody help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to generate a Login URL and redirect Users to that one, it´s explained in the docs for 3.x.x: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/

With manage_pages, it would be like this:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'manage_pages',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

I highly suggest upgrading to a server with PHP 5.4+ though.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't waste your time with using an outdated version of the PHP SDK, or is there a reason why you chose the old version?

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

on how to implement Facebook Login.

Comment: The reason is my server has PHP Version 5.3. and "The Facebook SDK for PHP v4 requires PHP 5.4 or greater."